# Upload files from multi input fields

Tags: javascript, ajax

I used to use this method to upload a file without refresh the page:
[AJAX file upload tutorial](http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html)

and it works fine, but now I need to upload multi files through multi input fields, something like that:

Personal Photo: `<input name="myfile1" type="file" />`

Certificate1 Image: `<input name="myfile2" type="file" />`

Certificate2 Image: `<input name="myfile3" type="file" />`

so how can I do that without re-write startUpload, and stopUpload function with a new title "like startUpload2, and stopUpload2 for 'myfile2' input, and another for myfile3... etc"?

Answer (score 0):

The `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your form will allow for multiple file uploads. For those functions you refer to, you will either have to loop through the inputs and apply the functions to each input or apply a slightly different function to the form itself.